# How to change linux kernel page size on x86?

Tags: linux, memory-management, kernel

It is known that the page size is 4KB on x86. If we have 64G RAM, then there are 16M page enteries, it will cause too mant tlb misses. In x86, we can enable PAE to access more than 4GB memory. (and the page size could split to 2MB per page?)

The Hugepagetlbfs permit us to use huge pages to get performance benefit(Eg: less tlb miss), but there are a lot of limitions:

- Must use share memory interface to write the Hugepagetlbfs
- Not all processes can use it
- Reserve memory may fail

So, if we can change the page size to 2M or 4M, then we can get the performance benefit.

In my way, I tried some ways to change it, but fail.

- Compile the kernel with CONFIG_HUGETLBFS, fail
- Compilt the kernel with CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE and CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE_ALWAYS, fail

Could somebody help me?

Comment: You realize that possible page sizes are hardware-restricted, right?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes, but there is a PSE way to change the default 4K/page to 4M/page. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_Size_Extension

Comment: It is call huge page on Linux

Comment: And I believe that many `mmap`-s would use it... so there is nothing to do actually, it is used!